# print the sum of digits in child and performing task in parent using fork() system call?

Tags: linux, fork

i know , when data changes each parent and child get a seperate memory page. is that possible we can do operation in parent and printing in child.
if possible please tell me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        static int i,n,s=0;
        printf("enter the number :  ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        if(fork() == 0)                                                                       {
                sleep(5);
                printf("s = %d\n",s);
        }
        else
        {
                for(;n;n = n/10)
                {
                        s = s+(n%10);
                }
                while(1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is very possible. You need interprocess communicatin (IPC) between the two. One common way is to use a [pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html). Do a search as there are many pipe examples.

Comment: not exactly correct but for checking output without infinite loop

    
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        static int i,n,s=0,c=0;
        printf("enter the number :  ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
L1:
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
                printf("s = %d\n",s);
        }
        else
        {
                for(;n;n = n/10)
                {
                        s = s+(n%10);
                }
        }
        c = c+1;
        if(c == 1)
                goto L1;
}

Comment: i got output : output what i got is this : 
enter the number :  123
s = 0
s = 0
s = 6
--> trying for different numbers
enter the number :  123456
s = 0
s = 0
s = 21
enter the number :  1122334455
s = 0
s = 30
s = 0
enter the number :  1234567
s = 0
s = 28
s = 0
enter the number :  11111111111111111111
s = 0
s = -1
s = 0